# Proof that $x^y + y^x > 1 \ \forall x,y > 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

The problem is trivial if at least one of $x$ or $y$ is greater than $1$.  So all we need is to proof that $x^y+y^x > 1 \ \forall x,y \in (0,1)$.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the limit doesn't exist as $(x,y) \to (0^+,0^+)$ as the path $x=0$ gives you $1$ and the path $y=x$ gives you $2$.

Comment: It may be of use to look at $1/x$ and $1/y$ with $x,y>1$ to Rephrase the condition as $$ \frac1{\sqrt[x]{y}}+\frac1{\sqrt[y]{x}}>1$$

Comment: Well, there is the brute force attack using the second derivative test for a function of two variables, but it would be a bit messy. One would find that the minimum occurs when either $x=1$ or $y=1$. Hopefully, there is a slicker way to do it.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/482549/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381090/42969 – all found instantly with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5Ey%20%2B%20y%5Ex%20%3E%201%24&p=1)

Comment: Thank you, I did search for the question on the site but I could not find it. I did not know about approach0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Bernoulli 
$$\frac{1}{x^y}=\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^y\leq1+y\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)=\frac{x+y-xy}{x}.$$
Thus,
$$x^y\geq\frac{x}{x+y-xy}>\frac{x}{x+y}$$
and we are done.

Comment: Isn't that essentially https://math.stackexchange.com/a/319620/42969 from the possible duplicate?

Comment: I took the time to find 3 identical questions with answers. Why don't you (at least) use your golden badge to close it as a duplicate? As you know, you can always add better answers to the other questions.

Comment: @Martin R Because I hope that my solution will give something new. I just like to prove inequalities more and more. Try to prove inequalities Martin R and I am sure that you'll understand me.

Comment: Apparently you still have not understood what "closing as a duplicate" is for and why it is a good thing to keep the site clean ...

Comment: @Martin R I think that you still don't understand that besides site cleanliness there is math. If you wish to close it like duplicate then  I will not protest.